# jQuery find('#selector').length causes error in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, jquery

Everything I have read says this is the proper way to test whether jQuery's find() matched on something:

```
var myVar = $(this).find('#gallery');
if (myVar.length) {
    alert('found');
} else {
    alert('not found');
}
```

This does work correctly, however in Chrome throws this error in the console whenever the element is not found:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Is there a cleaner way to test for whether find() matched anything - one that doesn't output an error in the console?  I have to run this comparison dozens of times and I feel like it's bad form for a programming to be spitting out console errors.

UPDATE: I was looking at the wrong file and posted the wrong code above.  $(this).find('#gallery').length is indeed the correct way to check whether there was a match, and does NOT throw an error in the Javascript console.

I tried to delete this question but am not allowed to do so.  Leaving it here in hopes that others find it helpful.

Comment: what is `this`? Using `length` of jQuery object is very common practice. Show context you are using code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `if (myVar != undefined && myVar.length)`